# Why are there two index-entries for each item for array-contains in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#index_entries_2), there are 2 single-field index entries (ASC and DESC) for array-contains for each of the items in the neighborhoods array:

| Index | Indexed Data |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| neighborhoods Array Contains ASC | neighborhoods: "Mission" |
| neighborhoods Array Contains DESC | neighborhoods: "Mission" |
| neighborhoods Array Contains ASC | neighborhoods: "Downtown" |
| neighborhoods Array Contains DESC | neighborhoods: "Downtown" |
| neighborhoods Array Contains ASC | neighborhoods: "Marina" |
| neighborhoods Array Contains DESC | neighborhoods: "Marina" |

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing) also says that:

> For each array field in a document, Cloud Firestore creates and maintains ***a*** collection-scope array-contains index.

It also shows only a single index mode for array-contains [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#index_modes).

The first link seems to contradict the last two. What am I missing? Why are there two entries for each item in the single-field index entries?

Comment: Can you please highlight/screenshot the _"there are 2 single-field index entries (ASC and DESC) for array-contains"_ part in the docs? Are you referring to the `for each non-array field` section?

Comment: The table that I have made is from the docs, and it shows 2 entries for each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone from the Firebase team will have to confirm, but to my understanding there are two `array-contains` indexes due to the ordering of the `__name__` field of each document - one where `__name__` is sorted in ascending order and the other where it is sorted in descending order.

The indexing of the `__name__` field is [covered in the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#default_ordering_and_the_name_field) where it states:

> By default, the `__name__` field is sorted in the same direction of the last sorted field in the index definition. To sort results by the non-default `__name__` direction, you need to create that index.

As an `array-contains` filter doesn't have an explicit direction, the entries in its results need to be indexed in both directions for when you sort the results by the document ID (`documentId()`) which uses `__name__` under the hood.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. That was my guess as well, but your explanation makes it clearer. I'll accept this answer as soon as someone from the firebase team confirms. Thanks.

Comment: *firebaser here* Great explanation Sam.  --- Each index always has a __name__ field indeed (which can either contain the document ID for regular indexes, or the document path for collection group indexes), to ensure it is unique. Until recently this __name__ field was not shown in the Firestore console, but we just started showing it to answer questions like this one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for confirming! I think it might help readers if the documentation includes this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing).